# This expression is not callable, Each members of the union

Tags: typescript, generics, types, entity-component-system

I have aligned my approach with my nearest current architecture, striving to minimize complexity as much as possible.

I have aimed for the closest approximation to a satisfactory result, but I encountered a single failed test with this approach.

I'm on the verge of giving up, as it has already been three days!
However, if your expertise can uncover a solution that ensures the success of all tests, it would be truly amazing!

the `getComponentFromEntity` is maybe the key, maybe need a black magic type pattern to solve this ?!

Thank you for your valuable time

[image]
[◽playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/PTCuBcEsBsGcAJwE8AOBTWAoZ74GEB7AO1nACdQBjcAsgHgBUA+eAXngG94i0B3ACgB0wgIZkA5rABc8EUSQBKGQ3gBfANzZUaeAFEAHuRHVCAWxTE0RcA22MW7FWkNWAJgl3XIyOpCIAzNDJ8FgB+fHgZHgA3IM0cHU8oKAw8MTQAWREUOjx4Z3A3BDMLHmsHeCycolBTACMggBo9Lx88JiYtXBLLa1t0RnyXInd8AnNe8DYxibLwCsIScioaemZ47XgGUBRoNAYCAEkluUoMAGZBgqL4MjQRV2JoJHhQIgBrIgJeIgBtAF0KhxMABIX4AaXgfng7zQSAI-i2-2UEP+Q0KI2KxFIFGotF8ASC8AAqmESeibhxVPBwsTItw0LFglFGXFMKpMF1EoYyMZwABlJCkNCmHpzWAAFjooP5FMx8AASqA9rBGqDIdd5QriQAZXT8zAVfmouWjMVWGzaAE0+DG8FozWjGJBa20j5fXjm6z07a7fZHE5EM6wS52wG-Gr1IJollMzSYPyFMj+Yw6QXC0zElCuESFOiyx0IdOFUzTYsi5oK00IJUqsu-ADkFBVDcBnFBFu8kAwMiSXdS6Sq0pBIIMRmo5dF41KFsldAVld1+sEAAsRLAAILQaCdEFMeMckBQ2CwUBoTmUaDrjytJDDvKFmYz73sL3gNUsYEg1xoS-peAoKAdTQJAlDwJQ06TNItpoOAuT7pyILiLBVzDGaTD8BBswWngV4njIiw4is+LMEoWztiOdzgKAZBEK8IxoP4fhoK4sgIG8nzfHR65bJoIIciOa6wKhGJmpBcwYeB4k4Xh0GEcseJrCwZHgCukAIOpLTJHezAUSCVE0XRKZwGgfEcuymAiHUOJ8uBslPpMFH+AQBD8AonBqBZmBWLUipLrKX5CVu0BqhyCSKsqGDTFwdwPE8LwQlCdHanq-L-KEBHSX0VpoholnWeOUx-ietpCiWFFWTZ1C3JF0G1hgfGVYV8DEFmOaFPw4AyJObW5mg+ZlRWEUqkwZHRAQkCuJo5nOBYZBFfZxLut8b7Vg5cwUQAxFhz7gAAhLGbIzfoc0Lde8Abqtj6rV+21Zfth1kNN3knbQZ0lQAQldaFYth3q3TtkwHQycYWbNb12edeDfaJv27VtgNzMDzpPWDr3zZDJUACIwzcN2gndf0PSDR0XvZk4bmtk4UYBwGgTVdbsF+YIpcuQXbsi8C-Jd93NF993-Gq-HxiCrXZn1-AcJ2KSwKo3WDZm4t5hTo16dL3awIIzlkLoxgrvw-D5PA7msJ+oIjmggjIeA-D80TChHoAvBuAEf7iBqQgsArgQyqsSg16CObIKW9b-A8-bTuu6pmme970C+-7gfB7B-DQ-dDvAPAjuACy7bvR17Pv5GQZC0IHkCIvwltCSnb4KO5zMW1byep+HGcu7nHv53HAEJyODchzjadOznUcd7HrFBMXZCByCZfwBXq7rvwA-23X09B43NvL7t6eZ5H7vwDHBd+yeAe9-xgcCfxChmV5nI-n+dxSUssh1L2t50Hbu0sAAPlp3h3p-Ryv9m5f3jMAAAVOA+AABxWCsgpJEwQP4YupZpYvHAcATA-g3jUEgMQeA1s3wADEUF9h8LoNaZCkDNAfD9PQPI+Rvn6P1XQHQK63l7M0RGFpMpLFxKseCZE8hfgMrRfIt4N6YTTs9TAhD7okPGFQ-gVk+Y13gBHduB9O7xxPrI2CxDSG3mUXUZoYdt7qNbsPfeh8u4T1oAHORRMFGmCUSo-Aaih6aJsePIu9jMAgAAHqhDvr+K8j8ILPxEG-bSH9VrALfAhEQkjAFzB3m3EeWix7d10UkkOZjJhpKsXnLJdiyBAA)

```
//utils types
type Constructor<T> = { new(...args: any): T };
type ExtractComponentType<T> = T extends Entity<infer C> ? C : never;
type EntitiesCareMap<C extends Component> = Map<number, Entity<C>>
type ComponentType<T extends Component = Component> = Constructor<T>;
type TupleToInstances3<T extends readonly unknown[]> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Constructor<infer U> ? U extends {} ? U : never : never;
}

type ExtractSystemComponents4<
    S extends Rules,
    K extends RULES
> = S[K] extends ComponentType[] ? S[K] extends never[] ? UnknowComponent : TupleToInstances3<S[K]>[number] : never;

interface SystemUpdate<S extends System = System, R extends Rules = S['rules']> {
    entities: EntitiesCareMap<
        ExtractSystemComponents4<R, RULES.hasAll>
    >;

}
// issue

class Entity<
    C extends Component = Component,
> {
    declare public components: Set<C>;

    get<T extends C>(componentClass: Constructor<T>): T {
        return undefined as unknown as T;
    }
        has<T extends Component>( componentClass: Constructor<T> ): this is Entity<T> {
        return false;
    }

}
abstract class Component {
    foo() { }
}

enum RULES {
    hasAll,
}
type Rules = { readonly [K in RULES]?: ComponentType[] };
abstract class System {
    abstract rules: Rules;
    abstract onUpdate(t: SystemUpdate<System, Rules>): void;
}

export class UnknowComponent extends Component {
    #component!: never;
}

export class AComponent extends Component {
    #component!: never;
}
export class BComponent extends Component {
    #component!: never;
}
export class CComponent extends Component {
    #component!: never;
}
export class DComponent extends Component {
    #component!: never;
}

class SystemA extends System {
    public rules = {
        [RULES.hasAll]: [AComponent, BComponent],
    };

    onUpdate({entities}: SystemUpdate<SystemA>) {
        entities.forEach(( e ) => {
            e.get(BComponent)//  this should pass.
            e.get(AComponent)//  this should pass.
            e.get(CComponent)//  this should error
            if (e.has(CComponent)) {
                e.get(CComponent)//  this should pass.
                e.get(DComponent)//  this should error
                if (e.has(DComponent)) {
                    e.get(DComponent)//  this should pass.
                }
            }
        });
    }
}



declare const ab: Entity<BComponent> | Entity<BComponent | CComponent>;

/** Get a components from entity */
function getComponentFromEntity<E extends Entity, C extends ExtractComponentType<E>>(entity: E, component: Constructor<C>): C {
    return entity.get(component);
}

getComponentFromEntity(ab, BComponent) //  this should pass.
getComponentFromEntity(ab, AComponent) //  this should error.
getComponentFromEntity(ab, CComponent) //  this should error.
//^?

declare const a: Entity<BComponent | CComponent>;
a.get(BComponent)//  this should pass.
a.get(AComponent)//  this should error
```

Comment: Are you trying to say that if `T` is a union of types then `ExtractComponentType<T>` should be the *intersection* of the results for each union member?  That is, `ExtractComponentType<A | B>` should be `ExtractComponentType<A> & ExtractCompoenntType<B>`?  If so then [this](https://tsplay.dev/weLnYW) is how you might do it and I believe gives you the behavior you're looking for.  If that meets your needs I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: in fake my fist issue was this : https://tsplay.dev/WGX69w
i gave up on this one to the new approach because i think it was impossible due to the architecture, but maybe with luck you have a magic solution!

Comment: and +1 for explanation when you will have 5min plz , i dont get your black magic  thank you so mutch for your time

Comment: I have to go to sleep but I'll write an answer when I wake up.  I'm afraid I don't understand [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76891793/this-expression-is-not-callable-each-members-of-the-union#comment135552305_76891793) much. Are you saying you need a different solution to a different version of the question?  I plan to answer the question that you actually asked and not some other version from the comments; I hope that's okay.

Comment: I've written very poorly, Sorry for my bad English. 
In fact, it was the first and original version of the issue that I abandoned after trying in all directions to make the polymorphisme and unions of the 2 entities work.
The diff is just Instead to call a function, we use local method and polymorphisme.
But ts throw error with generic.

I had concluded that it was probably impossible after many try, but I thought that maybe someone more experienced might have a solution to unlock this case.

Otherwise, it's not a big deal, the solution above you solved is more than suitable for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that you want `ExtractComponentType<T>` to turn [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) in `T` to [intersections](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) in the output type.  So `ExtractComponentType<A | B>` will be equivalent to `ExtractComponentType<A> & ExtractComponentType<B>`.  (That is, you want to [*distribute*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) your operation over unions in `T` but in a *contravariant* way (see [Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance and Bivariance in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218) for more info on variance).

That's because when you call `getComponentFromEntity(e, c)`, if `c` is of type `Entity<A | B>` then `c` can be either `A` or `B` (because `Entity<A | B>` accepts either), but if `c` is of type `Entity<A> | Entity<B>` then you don't know which it accepts, so `c` has to be both `A` *and* `B` for that to be safe.

So let's implement it.

---

Here's one way:

```
type ExtractComponentType<T> =
    (T extends Entity<infer C> ? ((x: C) => void) : never) extends
    (x: infer I) => void ? I : never;

type X = ExtractComponentType<Entity<BComponent | CComponent>>;
// type X = BComponent | CComponent
type Y = ExtractComponentType<Entity<BComponent> | Entity<CComponent>>;
// type Y = BComponent & CComponent
```

You can see that it works as intended.  The implementation uses a contravariance trick with conditional types, as described in  [Transform union type to intersection type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50374908/2887218).  Since function types are contravariant in their parameter types, we move the type into a function parameter position before inferring from it.

---

We're 95% of the way there.  Here's the rest:

```
function getComponentFromEntity<
    E extends Entity,
    C extends Component & ExtractComponentType<E>
>(entity: E, component: Constructor<C>): C {
    return entity.get(component);
}
```

All I had to do there is tell the compiler that `C` would definitely be a `Component` of some sort, to prevent the implementation from complaining.  TS can't really do higher order reasoning about [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) conditional types, so even though `ExtractComponentType<E>` must be compatible with `Component` by construction, the compiler fails to see it.  So I added `Component &` to fix that.

---

Let's test it:

```
declare const ab: Entity<BComponent> | Entity<BComponent | CComponent>;
getComponentFromEntity(ab, BComponent) //  okay
getComponentFromEntity(ab, AComponent) //  error!
getComponentFromEntity(ab, CComponent) //  error!

declare const a: Entity<BComponent | CComponent>;
a.get(BComponent)//  okay
a.get(AComponent)//  error!
```

Looks like the behavior you wanted!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/PTCuBcEsBsGcAJwE8AOBTWAoZ74GEB7AO1nACdQBjcAsgHgBUA+eAXngG94i0B3ACgB0wgIZkA5rABc8EUSQBKGQ3gBfANyZsqNPACiRKFAx4xaALIiUdPPDQAPcGiIATBIQC2KYs-At2ltZEoB4ARmhkADT6hpDINkxM2rie3jyGDDqMdo7ObvgEXj6GbAVF6X6lhCTkVDT0zJo4ugygKNBoDAQAkjVylBgAzNkOTq4IZGgiLsTQSPCgRADWRAS8RADaALr+nJgAkBsA0vCQRPBLaEgEAGbwDFvKx1s5Y-nVpBTUtHRnNxHwACqLAA-EDXnkEBxVPAwYD4DIeAA3AGItAosiaVRaZr6RxkETUADKSFIaA8qWK4FgABY6AciRDxvAAEqgDqwSIHE6jSGswEAGT0RMwuyJzyZ70KaV8mXQ21h8HFRxevOZyIiCrhy1WvEpFQR9zaHS6vVI-SGdGVOw2wTCEReaIxmkwZycZBuhN0JLJHkBKBcIicVslCB9Tg8pXD5OiLNDrPZGCjGwA5BQOSmdnt9r44pAMDIDEZ87BTJNAvT9vs9PjCeBoxTpVTaXQWbHBcLBAALESwACC0GgSX2TBd2JAp1gsFAaC0lGgvYQRbiSErtjVUvKviqTYqXJYHAOLjQ87M8BQoFC0EglHglF3vmkSrQ4ASLv24hfI1yzLwTH495boYeALlOMgfLU3wNEwSj3Nm+yTOAoBkOcizHjcZxoC4sgIIsKxrOcvb3Jo+zYvsPawN+bzuA+hj-oBMrAaBT4QV89SMDBMjgF2kAILxMRGKuzDwYhyHnJ6cBoCR2KYNiIihJ8dZ3sxZSMeA2Y3AQBD8AonBqLJWjOCE-JCoyh7kb2A7QFy2K4myHKlFwkzTLM8zHKc5wsh2RJbCC4G0eAcpoAqGiYPJinUMpi5KqSEbZuF5BKemBYJhyJEJQSkXEP6gZOPw4AyA2OVBmgVqxTGqUYJx8BIgQkAuFihn2N4ZDqaeU5Ajqaz6tuG40UB6nmQAxAxVIAIROhEjWYA4LVtSpfY9SUfWqVS2YjQFE3cOiU0GbNtDzdFABCS3qStp3raNFRbRqmJ7c1B1RR1eAXedAWXZtk13di+2tU9CAACKvT+m5qR9A03Tt31zipDZ9vGDbZheV43vAyUIOw5mHF5pndpZg6PPAGyLQF0QnQFWxcqR77ZQGJX8FwubGAgqiFeVfp08GcMwfBTMloImlkHohJdvw-BoLprAHgcVZoIIn7gPw5MDQoE6ALwbgBH+4gPEILAXYEOy2EoIuggyzm8svvwJMq+rWvcfxesG9ARsm2bcsK-wL0BarwDwGrgAsu9rDv64bdhkGQtBm5Adzi3jsCe6dCi6VjssW4rXs277mtB7rIfO+ertVqnHtA976uB-budO9hEQR2QZv7NH8CxxR-ClyrycN+bJeJ7bOfwI7ofG1OptF6RZtkaRCjSQZWg4joeKJdQp1BRxbAHPwKgrcu8R-ACf6KmL9jgZLLC1fVulfbpfUb8fHn-GQ8DdKfNV1dhYLdIat0uriAAapQ1iXuAFeWQd6rmVmDAAPvgU6iRNATj-qUCBa1oEZzUskXQABNABtZl4BVXmAugyCKgsGgYQtBVI4GYAQQvbB7BiHbgAGQwICloYAAAqdh8AADiL5ZB3gCggG4EdIxM3mOw4AmAbiLGoJAYg8AFanQAGIiMIQcPQ8YwFU3XCDfqYNmGAMysA-BoCkj-jEYWaIV1fD+RqGxH4f5YK2HMqJFCdhYjIDTgBb201jynkmAImoshQiFg8eA2B8AyFhKIRdVBsDNCKICiowoYD+DyTJoneAfcCBLBEEgTAiSBrJI8Kk9J8BrZqV0uXMOdcxoFJfMo1RYS0mhGiBQioVSs6B1rrQOpmA-ELgCfeIJIhQmCRie9OJAVRxhS8QwwwPs-ZaxyXk2ZHsKlUkWQHGpvSgA)

Comment: thank you so much for your time and the explantations, I will definitely have to deepen my research on Variance, Covariance, Contravariance and Covariance.
These terms were unfamiliar to me and the contravariance trick is hard to digest at the moment.
I also close the discord discutions and link here for more context.
https://discord.com/channels/508357248330760243/1139987469144694876